# display the block based on class name

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the div section which is generated dynamically.

```
<div class="webform submission-1">
   <span class="first">1</span>
   <span class="second">11</span> 
</div>
<div class="webform submission-2">
   <span class="first">2</span> 
   <span class="second">22</span> 
</div>
<div class="webform submission-3">
   <span class="first">3</span> 
   <span class="second">33</span>  
</div>
<div class="webform submission-4">
   <span class="first">4</span> 
   <span class="second">44</span>  
</div>
 ...
<div class="webform submission-12">
   <span class="first">12</span> 
    <span class="second">1212</span>  
</div>
```

I want to display span class="second" and hide class="first" between submision-1 to submission-3 and to display span class="first" and hide class="second" between submision-4 to submission-12
 using jquery how to check the class name is exist with dynamic class name and add display property.

```
 if($('.submission-2').length>0){ //need to check the between submission-1 to submission-3
$('.second').css('display','block');
$('.first').css('display','none');
}
else if($('.submission-4').length>0){ //need to check the between submission-4 to submission-12
$('.second').css('display','none');
$('.first').css('display','block');
}
```

Comment: what is `addCss` - never heard of this function before - sure it is not just `css("propertyname","value")`

Comment: I'm not sure what `addCss` is, but jQuery uses `css()`.

Comment: Now that you've edited the question in favour of `.css()`, what seems to be the problem? Errors? Give us more details...

Answer (score 3):

Don't use JS for this. CSS is more than capable of achieving this more effectively by using the `:nth-child` selector.

```css
.webform:nth-child(-n+3) .first {
  display: none;
}
.webform:nth-child(n+4) .second {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="webform submission-1">
   <span class="first">1</span>
   <span class="second">11</span> 
</div>
<div class="webform submission-2">
   <span class="first">2</span> 
   <span class="second">22</span> 
</div>
<div class="webform submission-3">
   <span class="first">3</span> 
   <span class="second">33</span>  
</div>
<div class="webform submission-4">
   <span class="first">4</span> 
   <span class="second">44</span>  
</div>
<div class="webform submission-12">
   <span class="first">12</span> 
    <span class="second">1212</span>  
</div>
```

Here's some further reading on the [`:nth-child selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

Comment: To add a little explanation for less experienced people in the future : `:nth-child(-n+3)` allows you to pick elements less than the value in the same type, within the same parent element - meaning that element `submission-1, submission-2 and submission-3` will be selected - vice versa `(n+4)` means number 4 and up.

Comment: @Stender good point that the selector could do with some explanation, thanks. I also added a link to the relevant MDN page.

Comment: any one div can load dynamically based on ID need to check the class name this condition check the child

Comment: In that case, do you have control over the HTML? If you identify the containers with a `data` attribute instead of a class this becomes much simpler